# Stanford NER throws exception on docker

Tags: java, .net, docker, mono, stanford-nlp

I have a .net 472 executable which uses the https://www.nuget.org/packages/Stanford.NLP.NER/ nuget package.

```cs
            var classifierPath = (config.ClassifierDirectory ?? DEFAULT_CLASSIFIER_DIRECTORY) + @"\english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz";
            _entityClassifier = CRFClassifier.getClassifierNoExceptions(classifierPath);
```

This works absolutely fine on windows.

However when I create a linux docker container and run it on mono I get this exception:

> There was an error processing the request.
>   Error:edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.IOException:
>   Unable to open
>   "Stanford\Classifiers\english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz" as class
>   path, filename or URL

I have checked, and the file definitely exists inside the docker container.

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM mono

RUN apt-get update

RUN mkdir /dotnet

WORKDIR /dotnet

ARG PROJECT_NAME

COPY $PROJECT_NAME/bin/Release/net472/publish .

ENV ENTRY_POINT=$PROJECT_NAME.exe

RUN rm config.json

RUN chmod a+rwx -R .

CMD mono $ENTRY_POINT
```

Can anyone suggest what the cause of this might be, and how I can fix it?

EDIT:

I am an official idiot. All I had to do was change from windows paths to linux paths:

```cs
            var classifierPath = (config.ClassifierDirectory ?? DEFAULT_CLASSIFIER_DIRECTORY) + @"/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz";
```

works absolutely fine!

Comment: I'm not sure what to do here. I don't want to delete the question, as it's possible someone else may run into a similar issue one day. However i want to mark it as closed.